# how to determine the element ID of div that is positioned x pixels to the right of visible screen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hitting a wall with this one, hope someone can lend a hand.  I have a wrapper div containing many fixed-width "content" divs.  It's like a table, except that the number of items "per row" aren't fixed, so that whenever the screen size is wide, more items fit onto the screen.  Pretty basic.

Also, each of these "content" divs has an adjacent "details" div that is hidden by default ("style=display:none"), and an adjacent "separator" div that is empty, containing only the style "clear:both;".

Each content/details/separator div has a unique number in its ID, so that I can tell they are related (e.g., content123, details1234, separator1234)

Now, when one of these content divs is clicked, I want to reveal its "details" div below it.  That part, I've got working partially, by wrapping an anchor tag around the content div, which fires an onClick javascript event, which in turns runs a jQuery statement to make visible the details and separator divs `jQuery(".details1234").css("display","block");"`

But you can imagine my problem.  Once that "separator" div is reveled, it pushes down (clears) any "content" divs that appears to the right of it, ugly.  My thought, what I have been wrestling with for hours, is to reveal the "separator" div of the content div, that is the last one appearing in the "row" that was clicked.  That way, a new "row" will be opened up by the separator, so that when the "content" div is revealed it appears below the clicked item in the new row. To do that, I need to figure out the elementID of the last content div in the "row", and I was thinking about using the Y-coord of the mouse click event, plus the X-coord = to the right-most edge of the wrapper div minus half the width of the fixed-width content div. Something like that.  But I am smashed into a wall and can't figure it out.

Can anyone help me do that?  Or offer a different solution?
If sample code would help let me know, I could whip up an example, but it may take some screen space in this post.

Thanks everyone.. going nuts with this.

EDIT:  the sample code below is based on my site.  When a cell is clicked, you can see its "details" div appear below it, but unfortunately the other divs in the "row" get pushed down.  that is the effect I'm trying to avoid.  When a cell is clicked, I want the "details" to appear below it, but also the other divs to stay in their positions above the other cell's details, basically I want to keep the "row" intact.  In the code, you can see my fruitless experiments using a "separator" div, because my assumption is that if I can insert that after the last div in the row, then the "details" div will become the next row, followed then by the next row of cells.  Hope I explained it OK.  Thanksgiving feast causing blood to divert from brain ;)

```
    <html>
  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

  #overallwrapper{
    background: #CCCCCC; 
    padding-top: 4px; 
    padding-left: 4px; 
    padding-right: 4px; 
    padding-bottom: 4px; 
    margin-top: 5px;  
  }


 .contentcell{
    border: 2px solid blue; 
    padding: 4px;
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
  }

  .separator{
    clear:both;
    display: none;
  }


  .details{
    background:lightgreen;
    border: 2px solid green;
    width:450px;
    display:none;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showDetails(contentid){

   //first, reset all highlights and close any open content divs
   $("#overallwrapper .contentcell").css("border","2px solid blue");
   $(".details").css("display","none");
   $(".separator").css("display","none");   

   //now highlight the clicked div and reveal its content div
   var contentHI = "#content"+contentid;
   var detailsON = "#details"+contentid;
   var separatorON = "#separator"+contentid;
   $(contentHI).css("border","2px solid green");
   //$(separatorON).css("display","block");   
   $(detailsON).css("display","block");
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="overallwrapper">
      <div id="contentwrapper01">
        <div id="content01" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('01');">cell01</a></div> 
        <div id="details01" class="details">here are details about cell01</div>   
        <div id="separator01" class="separator">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper02">
    <div id="content02" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('02');">cell02</a></div> 
        <div id="details02" class="details">here are details about cell02</div>   
        <div id="separator02" class="separator"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper03">
        <div id="content03" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('03');">cell03</a></div> 
        <div id="details03" class="details">here are details about cell03</div>   
        <div id="separator03" class="separator"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper04">
        <div id="content04" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('04');">cell04</a></div> 
        <div id="details04" class="details">here are details about cell04</div>   
        <div id="separator04" class="separator"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper05">
        <div id="content05" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('05');">cell05</a></div> 
        <div id="details05" class="details">here are details about cell05</div>   
        <div id="separator05" class="separator"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper06">
        <div id="content06" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('06');">cell06</a></div> 
        <div id="details06" class="details">here are details about cell06</div>   
        <div id="separator06" class="separator"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- to prevent parent collapse -->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't visualise what you are seeing or doing, can you post this to a site somewhere that we can take a look?

Comment: @user did you try the answer i suggested

Comment: added sample code to original post, and updated my profile , my display name is now "jhalsey"

Comment: @gov: yes, I was attempting it, experimented with z-index and tried to figure out how to use offset. problem is, i don't know which div is at the end of the screen row.  i haven't found a way to determine that yet.

Answer (score 0):

User ,

if you give as regular position be default , it pushes the other contents definetly down as they come in squence.

Change the hidden divs position to absolute so that it will go out of sequence and you can position at anywhere on the page by top and left property.

get the offset of the div you want next to...

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

it will have top and left property , use those property's and position next to them.

let me know if you need anything else.

give a bigger z-index for the hidden divs.

Answer (score 0):

What about showing the details `div` with `position: absolute`, on top of everything else? (See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jVrby/), the code's a little messy but you get the idea).

Comment: hmmmm.  that is interesting, like a tooltip. as a last resort that could work for me.  I was hoping though, to push down the next row, so that the "details" div does not overlay the next row of divs.  also quirky is, it works in jsfiddle, but when i copy the code into an html file and run on my PC, the details div always overlays cell01 in the top left corner, it doesn't appear under the selected cell like a tooltip.  weird.

Answer (score 0):

I partially figured it out, but the logic may be very clunky. I basically walk left by 100px from the width of the container div until I find a content div. Plus it doesn't work in IE8, because IE is not getting the same results from jQuery's offset() or position() as firefox, it always reports "19".  So in IE, I can never get a Y-coordinate value.  I'm too sleepy now to work on this anymore today.  If someone can lend a hand or tell me how to improve the javascript that would be cool.

Here is the working code for Firefox (I changed javascript and css of the detail divs, compared to original question):

```
    <html>
  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

  #overallwrapper{
    background: #CCCCCC; 
    padding-top: 4px; 
    padding-left: 4px; 
    padding-right: 4px; 
    padding-bottom: 4px; 
    margin-top: 5px;  
  }


 .contentcell{
    border: 2px solid blue; 
    padding: 4px;
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
  }

  .separator{
    clear:both;
    display: none;
  }


  .details{
    background:lightgreen;
    border: 2px solid green;
    display:none;
    clear:both;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showDetails(contentid){

   //first, reset all highlights and close any open content divs
   $("#overallwrapper .contentcell").css("border","2px solid blue");
   $(".details").css("display","none");
   $(".separator").css("display","none");   

   //now highlight the clicked div and reveal its content div
   //first, figure out which separator to display.
   //1.get the y-pos from the clicked element, this gives y-coord of the row
   contentClicked = "#content"+contentid;
   var clickedoffset = $(contentClicked).offset();
   var ypos = clickedoffset.top;
   var wrapperwidth = $("#overallwrapper").width();
   for (var xpos=wrapperwidth; xpos>0; xpos-=100){
       var elematpos = document.elementFromPoint(xpos, ypos);
       var elematposid = elematpos.id;
       if (elematposid.substring(0,7) == "content") {
         var lastcontentdivID = elematposid.substring(7);
         break;
       }
   }

   $(contentClicked).css("border","2px solid green");
   var detailsON = "#details"+contentid;
   $(detailsON).css("display","block");
   var lastidonscreen = "#content"+lastcontentdivID;
   $(detailsON).insertAfter(lastidonscreen);

 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="overallwrapper">
      <div id="contentwrapper01">
        <div id="content01" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('01');">cell01</a></div> 
        <div id="separator01" class="separator">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="details01" class="details">here are details about cell01</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper02">
    <div id="content02" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('02');">cell02</a></div> 
        <div id="separator02" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details02" class="details">here are details about cell02</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper03">
        <div id="content03" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('03');">cell03</a></div> 
        <div id="separator03" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details03" class="details">here are details about cell03</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper04">
        <div id="content04" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('04');">cell04</a></div> 
        <div id="separator04" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details04" class="details">here are details about cell04</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper05">
        <div id="content05" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('05');">cell05</a></div> 
        <div id="separator05" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details05" class="details">here are details about cell05</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper06">
        <div id="content06" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('06');">cell06</a></div> 
        <div id="separator06" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details06" class="details">here are details about cell06</div>   
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- to prevent parent collapse -->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
Blasted IE.  I just can't trust it to determine screen coordinates.  I got it working though, but only for Firefox.  again IE is trying to drive me insane by not handling insertAfter properly.  arrgh!  here is the final code:

```
    <html>
  <head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

  #overallwrapper{
    background: #CCCCCC; 
    padding-top: 4px; 
    padding-left: 4px; 
    padding-right: 4px; 
    padding-bottom: 4px; 
    margin-top: 5px;

  }

 .contentwrapper{
  }

 .contentcell{
    padding: 4px;
    float: left; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
   border: 2px solid blue;
  }

  .separator{
    clear:both;
    display: none;
  }


  .details{
    background:lightgreen;
    border: 2px solid green;
    display:none;
    clear:both;
  }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
function showDetails(contentid){

   //first, reset all highlights and close any open content divs
   $("#overallwrapper .contentcell").css("border","2px solid blue");
   $(".details").css("display","none");
   $(".separator").css("display","none");   

   var contentClicked = "#content"+contentid;
   var thisypos = $(contentClicked).offset().top;
   var nextdivid = contentClicked;
   var countid = contentid;
   do
     {
     var prevdivid = nextdivid;
     var nextcontentid = (countid * 1) + 1;
     var nextcontentid = '' + nextcontentid;
     if ( nextcontentid.length < 2) 
     {  nextcontentid = "0" + nextcontentid; }
     nextdivid = "#content" + nextcontentid;
     if ( $(nextdivid).length ) {
       var nextypos = $(nextdivid).offset().top;
       countid++;
     } else {
       break;
     }
   }
   while (thisypos == nextypos);

   $(contentClicked).css("border","2px solid green");
   var detailsON = "#details"+contentid;
   $(detailsON).css("display","block");
   $(detailsON).insertAfter(prevdivid);

 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="overallwrapper">
      <div id="contentwrapper01" class="contentwrapper">
        <div id="content01" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('01');">cell01</a></div> 
        <div id="separator01" class="separator">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="details01" class="details">here are details about cell01</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper02" class="contentwrapper">
    <div id="content02" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('02');">cell02</a></div> 
        <div id="separator02" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details02" class="details">here are details about cell02</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper03" class="contentwrapper">
        <div id="content03" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('03');">cell03</a></div> 
        <div id="separator03" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details03" class="details">here are details about cell03</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper04" class="contentwrapper">
        <div id="content04" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('04');">cell04</a></div> 
        <div id="separator04" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details04" class="details">here are details about cell04</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper05" class="contentwrapper">
        <div id="content05" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('05');">cell05</a></div> 
        <div id="separator05" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details05" class="details">here are details about cell05</div>   
      </div>
      <div id="contentwrapper06" class="contentwrapper">
        <div id="content06" class="contentcell"><a href="javascript:showDetails('06');">cell06</a></div> 
        <div id="separator06" class="separator"></div>
        <div id="details06" class="details">here are details about cell06</div>   
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- to prevent parent collapse -->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```